# How to run javaws from 32 bit 'jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-i586.bin' on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit?

Tags: 18.04, java, 64-bit, 32-bit, jdk

I need to run a web based software that supports only jdk 1.5 32 bit on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit OS.How to run jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-i586.bin on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit? I need to open a JNLP file with javaws inorder to run the software. javaws is not opening.

I tried the following already,

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
sudo apt-get install multiarch-support
sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386
```

When i execute javaws from terminal it is stuck at 'java loading' for some time and then fails

```
itadmin@MT-MRD:~/Desktop/java/jdk1.5.0_06/jre/bin$ ./javaws

itadmin@MT-MRD:~/Desktop/java/jdk1.5.0_06/jre/bin$ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/itadmin/Desktop/java/jdk1.5.0_06/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1751)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1647)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:769)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:967)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1751)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1668)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:822)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:992)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1509)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1530)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

Comment: Your question says you want install [J2SE(TM) Development Kit 5.0 Update 6](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html) which is a self-extracting Linux .bin file. @Arun, just may [download](http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/1.5.0_06/jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-i586.bin) 46.7 MB size, `chmod +x jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-i586.bin` and run it on command line from Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-i586.bin is getting installed without any errors , but  i need to run a jnlp file with java web start (javaws) inside the installed jdk directory. javaws is not working

Comment: What was your installation path of jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-i586.bin @Arun?

Comment: itadmin@MT-MRD:~/Desktop/java$ ls
ADDITONAL_LIB_FILE_FOR_LINUX_CLIENT  jdk1.5.0_06  jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-i586.bin

Comment: i installed it from a directory java in Desktop

Comment: The Error is missing a file (libXext.so.6). The file could be found via packages.ubuntu.com: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libXext  ... I don't think it is a Ubuntu r Java issue, it seems to be related to the requirements of your JLNP file ... Are you sure you want to execute a such old Java Web application? Last time I did this I've set up an Windows XP VM, completely isolated with the related device.

Comment: The `locate libXext.so.6` command says that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6` is available. Try `locate libXext.so.6` from your dektop @Arun. But you need 32-bit version. If it is available, then set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point correct lib directory

Comment: @Arun, you may try install  [Missing libXext 32-bit library](https://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/Diag/MissingLibXext) `sudo apt-get install libxext6:i386`

Comment: Thankyou guys that worked , it seems like the missing 32 bit library file libXext was the issue. Now the application is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Downloaded and installed `jdk-1_5_0_06-linux-i586.bin` on `~/Desktop`
2. Installed `libxext6` 32-bit version

   `$ sudo apt-get install libxext6:i386`
3. Ran the following commands:

   `$ cd ~/Desktop/jdk1.5.0_06/bin`

   `$ ./javaws`
4. The following screen poped-out
   [image]

@Arun, please let me know my little research is helpful to you or not!

Comment: Thankyou guys that worked , it seems like the missing 32 bit library file libXext was the issue. Now the application is working, After opening the jnlp file with javaws , i had to execute the javaws from jdk.../jre/bin/javaws to install the shortcut for the application, now everything is working fine as expected, Thank you all